# How would I go about accessing a String object stored in the registry form a Flow? (Mule ESB 3.3)

Tags: salesforce, mule

I have some passwords that I access via a custom written java class and save the decrypted values in the Registry as String objects.(Note: we do not have access to the Enterprise Edition to leverage the Credentials Vault features.)

I can successfully save them and access them in code but I am having trouble accessing it in the flow.  Specifically the Salesforce connector:

```
<sfdc:config name="ConfigurableSalesforceConnection" username="${sfdc.username}" password="#app.registry.get('salesforcepassword')" securityToken="${sfdc.securityToken}" doc:name="Salesforce" url="${sfdc.url}"/
```

Some of the Syntax I have used is:

```
password="#app.registry.get('salesforcepassword')"
```

and

```
app.registry['salesforcepassword']
```

Is this even possible or should I explore different avenues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#[app.registry['salesforcepassword']]
```

Comment: Thanks this works I can now access it from a logger and print out the correct value, the Salesforce connector is still giving some issues though...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dealing with the registry, you could also encrypt the credentials in your properties file and use Jasypt to decrypt them when the file gets loaded. This is transparent for the application and way easier.

Check this tutorial: http://www.jayway.com/2008/12/09/encrypting-properties-with-jasypt/