# Mule ESB 3.3 Mulecontext Registry pop

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

I have recently asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279894/how-would-i-go-about-accessing-a-string-object-stored-in-the-registry-form-a-flo) where I asked how to reference a String object in the mule registry from a Mule Flow.  That has been successfully answered my current problem is that I cannot populate this in the registry before the flow is initialized.

Thus in the following segment (password="#app.registry['password']]) null is always used and my connection fails:

```
<sfdc:config name="ConfigurableSalesforceConnection"username="${sfdc.username}"password="#app.registry['password']]"securityToken="${sfdc.securityToken}"doc:name="Salesforce" url="${sfdc.url}" />
```

Amongst other things I have added a listener to my flow, but this adds the value too late and the flow has already been initialized.

```
<notifications>
    <notification event="CONTEXT"/>
    <notification-listener ref="Initializer"/>
</notifications>
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="Initializer" name="Initializer"
        class="initializer.InitAccountSync" />
</spring:beans>
```

My question consists of two parts, firstly is there a way to fore the reinitialization of a flow after start-up, and/or how can I store a value in the mule-context registry before said initialization?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry is shared with Spring, you can register some java.lang.String beans using SpEL or  a MethodInvokingFactoryBean.

However, for this case, if you are not retrieving it outside mule, what I would recommend is leverage [jasypt](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/encrypting-passwords-in-mule/).

Comment: I've suggested Jasypt on the other thread: that is the way to go IMO, instead of messing around with the registry.

Comment: @DavidDossot I agree, I think I have wasted enough time on the other approach.  Thanks for the links.